# Portlet Vs Servlet : why there is only Service phase in servlet and Action and render phase in portlet for request handling?

Tags: java, servlets, portlet

There is only Service Phase for servlet and Action and Render phase for portlet for request handling why?

Comment: Where did you find the term `Service Phase`?

Comment: @SteveC actually that is service method.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet API was designed for handling HTTP requests sent from a browser and returning a suitable response.

The portlet API is an abstraction that has been designed around the idea of a browser page being composed of a number of components (portlets) and presented in a portal. Portlet implementations are typically built on top of the servlet API.

The fact the portlet API utilises the notion of phases (action and render) is almost certainly a consequence of it having been designed by the same group that invented Java Server Faces (JSF), which also makes use of phased request/response processing. It is also built on top of the servlet API.